# Unable to Pos.CENTER in BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, borderpane

```
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    Button chooseFile = new Button("chooseFile");
    TextField fileLocation = new TextField("C:/");
    Button makeGrid = new Button("Solve");
    HBox fileLoad = new HBox(chooseFile, fileLocation, makeGrid);

    root.setTop(lastfil);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(root, Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    BorderPane.setMargin(root, new Insets(12,12,12,12));
    root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
```

I'm having some issues centering this, I want the prefSize to be 500 x 500 and have the file loader top center, but it does not do that. It is top but I am unable to get it to the center of the top. Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

BorderPane sets the alignment and Margin for the child node.

> BorderPane.setAlignment(Node child, Pos value)
>
> BorderPane.setMargin(Node child, Insets value)

So replace Borderpane 'root' to child node 'fileLoad ' as:

```
BorderPane.setAlignment(fileLoad, Pos.TOP_CENTER);
BorderPane.setMargin(fileLoad, new Insets(12,12,12,12));
```

Also set the child HBox alignment like:

```
fileLoad.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Refer [Class BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) to more info.